# Rails best practice for multiple associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, polymorphism

I have three models in my program, in kind of a hierarchical structure:

```
User (has_many :computers)
Computer (has_many :programs, belongs_to :user)
Programs (belongs_to :computer)
```

Within the program, I have a need to see how many Programs a User has by extensions.  This is pretty easy to do via `User.computers.programs`.

That said, would it be beneficial in any way to declare a `has_many/belongs_to` relationship between `Users` and `Programs` directly?  Would there be any benefit (performance or otherwise), or would it just add complexity to the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It largely depends on whether you foresee requiring to access that relationship often. If you can do without that particular query, you'll be better served to just use a

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :computers
  has_many :programs, :through => :computers
end
```

and be done with it. Less code that accomplishes the same is easier to read/maintain.

But if you will be making accessing that relationship over a large dataset it might payoff to denormalize your data a bit in the way you describe in the name of saving expensive `JOIN`s.

Comment: Wait, I accepted this, but I'm a bit lost.  How would the other classes look?  Would I have to say that a computer "belongs_to" a program?

Answer (score 0):

There's `through` option:

```
has_many :programs, through: :computers
```

You can read more about it here:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :computers
  has_many :programs, :through => :computers
end
```

That way you can just do:

```
user = User.first #find some user
user.programs #get a list of programs from the user through the computers they own
```